# Seleccionar cualquier resultado de una busqueda y enviar las variables a otra pagina en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy diseñando una intranet, de la cual requiero que el usuario cuando realice una solicitud de un producto, sea capaz de seleccionarlo directamente de la base de datos y enviar dicha solicitud.

De la pagina donde se origina la solicitudes le agregue un boton de busqueda para que el usuario busque el producto especifico y lo agregue a su solicitud, esto lo hice con ajax live search.

De los resultados de esa busqueda, generalmente se despliega un listado con los posibles resultados, el objetivo, y es en donde estoy bloqueado, es que de la lista con posibles resultados, el usuario elija el que desee y este se inserte en la solicitud de la pagina padre.

Tengo estos archivos del live search en ajax, php y mysql:

search-form.php (popup):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "", "database");
  if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  load_data();
  function load_data(query)
    {
      $.ajax({
      url:"backend-search.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{query:query},
      success:function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
$('#search').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
    if(search != ''){
      load_data(search);
    }else{
      load_data();
    }
 });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="wall">
    <section class="content">
          <div class="box box-default">
          <div class="box-header with-border"></div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="row">
              <h3>Ricerca Prodotto</h3>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Cerca il codice" class="form-control" style="width: 300px;" />
                  <div id="result"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

backend-search.php (mismo popup)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "", "database");
if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$content = '';
    if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["query"]);
        $query = $sql = "SELECT * FROM spesa_articoli_disponibili WHERE Codice_Articolo_CAPP LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR  ARTICOLO_Descrizione LIKE '%" . $search . "%'";
        }
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $content .= '
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
                <div class="group">
                </div>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $codice = $row["Codice_Articolo_CAPP"];
        $articolo = $row["ARTICOLO_Descrizione"];
        $content .= '
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <form method="post" id="searchform">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Codice Articolo</th>
                                    <th>Descrizione Articolo</th>

                                </tr>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="number" id="codice" name="codice" value="' . $codice . '" style="width: 70px;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="articolo" name="articolo" value="' . $articolo . '" style="width: 100%" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="button" value="Aggiungi" onclick="getValue();" /></td>
                                    <td><a href="JavaScript:window.close()">Chiudi</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </table>
                    <div id="resultado"></div>
                </div>';
            }
    echo $content;
        } else {
            echo "Non ci sono risultati. Riprova.";
            }
mysqli_close($link);
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
            var codice = window.opener.document.getElementById("codice");
            codice.value = document.getElementById("codice").value;
            var articolo = window.opener.document.getElementById("articolo");
            articolo.value = document.getElementById("articolo").value;
        }
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Hasta ahora no logro seleccionar el resultado de la busqueda y enviar las variables a la pagina padre.
Ideas, ayuda, sugerencias, todas seran bien recibidas.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Devuelves los resultado en una tabla. Puedes agregar: un <a href> en el id, un radio button y con Ajax hacer el insert.

Comment: Epa @Bicho gracias por responder, agregar un radio button para seleccionar un resultado y despues pasarlo a la pagina, no es igual que simplemente darle click al boton correspondiente en la lista de resultados?

Comment: Si, pero igual debes enviar a esa función todos los datos de ese registro, sino cómo identificarías la fila seleccionada de varios resultados?

Comment: A menos que sea un caso muy específico, donde realmente necesites una ventana nueva (popup), creo que la mejor opción sería usando un modal, estando todo dentro de la misma página es mucho más fácil tomar la información y enviarla a una función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como solución a mi pregunta, modifique como se mostraba resultado de la búsqueda, sustituí los input de las tablas por contenedores de html y en vez de utilizar javascript lo reemplace con JQuery, el objetivo siempre fue seleccionar cualquier resultado de la lista desplegada y que el mismo fuera insertado en los inputs correspondientes de la pagina padre.
Como mostraba los resultados anteriormente:

```
$content .= '
            <div>
                <div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <form method="post" id="searchform">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Codice Articolo</th>
                                <th>Descrizione Articolo</th>

                            </tr>
                    </div>
                        <div>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="number" id="codice" name="codice" value="' . $codice . '" style="width: 70px;" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="articolo" name="articolo" value="' . $articolo . '" style="width: 100%" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                                <td><input type="button" value="Aggiungi" onclick="getValue();" /></td>
                                <td><a href="JavaScript:window.close()">Chiudi</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </table>
                <div id="resultado"></div>
            </div>';
        }
echo $content;
```

Como se muestran ahora:

```
 $content .= '
    <div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="child" data-id="' . $codice . '" data-id2="' . $articolo . '"><span>COD: ' . $codice . ' - DESC: ' . $articolo . '</span></div>
        </div> 

    </div>

            <div>

                <div id="resultado"></div>
            </div>';
    }
echo $content;
```

en cuanto al Javscript, este era el viejo:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function getValue() {
        var codice = window.opener.document.getElementById("codice");
        codice.value = document.getElementById("codice").value;
        var articolo = window.opener.document.getElementById("articolo");
        articolo.value = document.getElementById("articolo").value;
    }
    window.close();
}
```

por JQuery:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".child span").click(function(){

        code = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
        articolo = $(this).parent().attr('data-id2');
        window.opener.$('#codice').val(code);
        window.opener.$('#articolo').val(articolo);
        window.close();
    });
```

})

obteniendo el resultado deseado.

Gracias a todos por la ayuda y su contribucion.